# The usage of yet in the sentence

Tags: word-usage

As I know, the word yet is usually used in a negative sentence. But if it's used in a positive sentence as below,  would it imply a negative meaning here as well?

> "We have **yet** to detect any signs of immediate provocations from North
>   Korea,"

Answer (score 1):

> "**We have yet to do something**" simply means "**we have not done it yet**" ([Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yet))

See definition **have yet to** in the link above.

> We use *have yet to* and *be yet to* in more formal contexts to refer to events which are necessary or which must happen at some time, but which have not happened at the time of speaking.

Comment: Thanks! I look into the link. There is an example "The President and her husband are yet to arrive." there. I am curious what would be the difference if I say "The President and her husband have yet to arrive.", compared with the original example?

Answer (score 0):

"yet" means at this point in time, but at a future point in time the situation it refers (object of the sentence) may change.  There is no negative or positive so your question makes no sense.

As an example, "Kim Yung Un has not released a real nuclear bomb yet, but he is such a lunatic, it is only a matter of time until he does."

Comment: Isn't it implying a negative here as you interpret the sentence as "Kim Yung Un has not released..."?